# Cobertura de testes usando Sonar

Tags: testes, integração, integração-contínua, selenium-webdriver, sonarqube

Gostaria de saber se alguém ai já utilizou o `Sonar` para fazer análise de cobertura de testes, estou com o seguinte problema, tenho dois projetos.

**Projeto A**: Esta implementado os meus testes, usando `Selenium + Testng`
**Projeto B**: É projeto em que quero avaliar a cobertura dos testes.

Gostaria de saber se existe alguma maneira de configurar o `Sonar` de forma que ao executar o **projeto A**, a análise de cobertura seja feita sobre o código do projeto B?

Answer (score 1):

Não cheguei a fazer isso, mas segundo a [documentação do Sonar](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Runner#AnalyzingwithSonarQubeRunner-Multi-moduleProject) você pode configurar um projeto multi-módulo e incluir vários projetos através de certas configurações no arquivo `sonar-project.properties`.

Por exemplo, considere a seguinte estrutura de pastas:

[image: Estrutura dos projetos]

Arquivo de configuração:

```
# Root project information
sonar.projectKey=org.mycompany.myproject
sonar.projectName=My Project
sonar.projectVersion=1.0

# Some properties that will be inherited by the modules
sonar.sources=src

# List of the module identifiers
sonar.modules=module1,module2
```

Answer (score 1):

Olha, não conseguimos medir realmente a cobertura de testes quando se utiliza Selenium porque não conseguimos, de maneira clara ligar o código-fonte aos scripts de teste com Selenium como ocorre com testes unitários (que tem a instrumentação dos bytecodes para fazer essa ligação).

A cobertura baseada em automações funcionais/aceitação são referentes a requisitos/aceite, e não sobre código, o que impossibilita esta análise de cobertura.
Leitura recomendada: http://java.dzone.com/articles/code-coverage-metrics-and

O que há mais perto disso, por exemplo, é conseguir rastrear um cenário/critério de aceite e analisar a cobertura sobre este. Há um ferramenta que faz isso e tem integração com o Sonar chamada [Thucydides](http://www.thucydides.info/)

Dê uma olhada [neste exemplo](http://wakaleo.com/thucydides-sample-reports/) de relatório.
[Aqui](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2078448/open-source-tools/selenium-2-and-thucydides-for-atdd.html) há um exemplo de uso.